# Question about "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$": Proper ideals are invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I am reading through Cox's book *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* and I am stuck with some proofs in Chapter 7 (I have the 2nd edition). There, the author presents the following Lemma:

> **Lemma 7.5:** Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\tau)$ be a quadratic field, and let $ax^2+bx+c$ be the minimal polynomial of $\tau$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime integers. Then $[1,\tau]$ is a proper fractional ideal for the order $[1,a\tau]$ of $K$.

Shortly after, he proceeds to prove that proper fractional ideals for an order of a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ are invertible.

> First note that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$ (see Exercise 7.8), so that $\mathfrak{a}=[\alpha, \beta]$ for some $\alpha, \beta\in K$. Then $\mathfrak{a}=\alpha [1, \tau]$, where $\tau=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$. If $ax^2+bx+c$, $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\tau$, then Lemma 7.5 implies that $\mathcal{O}=[1, a\tau]$.

I don't get how the above follows from Lemma 7.5. The same reasoning is used later in the proof of Lemma 7.14:

> If we write $\mathfrak{a}$ in the form $\mathfrak{a}=a[1,\tau]$, then Lemma 7.5 implies that $\mathcal{O}=[1, a\tau]$.

Any help in understanding how the author devises these conclusions would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Please* define the term "proper ideal" in your post! Anyone not already familiar with the topic of your question is likely to think "proper fractional ideal" is related to the notion of "proper subset," which is not what you mean.